# How to use ViXS PureTV-U 48A3 on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-media-center, tuner-card, device-manager

This may sound like a dumb question. But I have a computer with a "ViXS PureTV-U 48A3" tv-card. It comes with Windows Media Center. What exactly am I supposed to do in order to force this PC to output to my TV? Even though the device appears in Device Manager, neither Media Center nor the Display Properties seems to detect the TV as a 2nd monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this card as well with Vista. I haven't been able to find any specs on it to prove it, but I believe this card doesn't output video at all, it just takes input, as it's a TV tuner card. If your PC has an S-video port, then you could output the video to a TV.

Comment: I think you're right. I have not found any definitive specs either but opened up the computer and found the card is based on a "ASUS Combo-210" chipset... there are a few of these for sale on eBay and none of them claim to have a TV output.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that same card for about four years now.  There is no video output connector with that card, just the two RF input connectors--one for old analog TV and one for digital TV input.  The card has a separate RF tuner chip sets for the separate analog TV and digital TV signal processing.